# Android Web Wiew and Custom URL Scheme

Tags: android, url

I have a WebView App that point on my site (it's for a service for tech support and PC repair) Users can see their status by compiling the form (`http://service-lab.com/ServicePointHelpDesk/index.php#cerca`) with mobile number

The request is send with a GET form, so the query result is

```
http://service-lab.com/ServicePointHelpDesk/cerca.php?tel=3316282871
```

Ok, for now it's all ok and working..Automatically when the status change, the customer is notified with a mail, and i want that the link open the app with the result query.

```
http://service-lab.com/ServicePointHelpDesk/cerca.php?tel=3316282871
```

I've set up a CustomURL with this way:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
<data android:scheme="servicepoint"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

If i go to servicepoint:// the app starts correctly, but how can i process the PHP query? Like `servicepoint://tel=0000000000?`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```java
getIntent().getData()
```

returns the URI which it is called with in the activity, which is opened. So you could basically do something like:

```java
URI uri = getIntent.getData();
if (uri != null){
  String telephoneNumber = uri.getQueryParameter("tel");
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks i 'll check this soon.. But The main page is index.php.. And The query is on find.php ho Can i define this page?

Comment: Still open my app on homepage and not in the find.php?tel=xxxxx page =(

Comment: So that's the problem. Use android:pathPattern in your manifest.